# Add a flag indicating that a column has changed for each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has a company name for id as follows.

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    "company": ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F"]},
    columns=["id", "company"]
)
   id company
0   1       A
1   1       A
2   1       B
3   2       C
4   2       C
5   2       C
6   3       D
7   3       E
8   3       F
```

How can I add a flag indicating job change to the above DataFrame as follows?

```python
   id company  job_change
0   1       A           0
1   1       A           0
2   1       B           1
3   2       C           0
4   2       C           0
5   2       C           0
6   3       D           0
7   3       E           1
8   3       F           1
```

There is little explanation on how to take `diff` in `groupby` with pandas in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use custom function with compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed groups with replace `NaN`s by backward filling by `bfill`, last convert boolean mask to integer by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby('id')['company'].apply(lambda x :x.ne(x.shift().bfill())).astype(int)
print (df)
   id company  flag
0   1       A     0
1   1       A     0
2   1       B     1
3   2       C     0
4   2       C     0
5   2       C     0
6   3       D     0
7   3       E     1
8   3       F     1
```

And thank you, @pansen for better solution:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby("id")["company"].shift().bfill().ne(df['company']).astype(int)
print (df)
   id company  flag
0   1       A     0
1   1       A     0
2   1       B     1
3   2       C     0
4   2       C     0
5   2       C     0
6   3       D     0
7   3       E     1
8   3       F     1
```

Comment: I think you can drop `apply` which should make the solution a bit faster and easier to read like so `df.groupby("id")["company"].shift().bfill().ne(df["company"]).astype(int)`