# Add a flag indicating that a column has changed for each group, except if group has only one row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem which is similar to the one in this question:

[Add a flag indicating that a column has changed for each group in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109520/add-a-flag-indicating-that-a-column-has-changed-for-each-group-in-pandas)

with the exception that some of my groups only contain one single row. Here is an extension of the problem formulated in the question above:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,4,5,5,5],
    "company": ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F","G","H","I","J"]},
    columns=["id", "company"]
)
```

Now, the solution offered by [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) is really nice:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby("id")["company"].shift().bfill().ne(df['company']).astype(int)
```

which produces

```
id company  flag
0    1       A     0
1    1       A     0
2    1       B     1
3    2       C     0
4    2       C     0
5    2       C     0
6    3       D     0
7    3       E     1
8    3       F     1
9    4       G     1
10   5       H     0
11   5       I     1
12   5       J     1
```

but it has a drawback for my purposes. Indeed, for `id = 4`, I wish the flag to be 0, not 1 since there is no change. I've tried to change `shift` but haven't had any luck.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change that to:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby("id")["company"].apply(lambda x: x.shift().fillna(x).ne(x).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
    id company  flag
0    1       A     0
1    1       A     0
2    1       B     1
3    2       C     0
4    2       C     0
5    2       C     0
6    3       D     0
7    3       E     1
8    3       F     1
9    4       G     0
10   5       H     0
11   5       I     1
12   5       J     1
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change the `bfill` method to `fillna`:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby('id')['company'].shift().fillna(df['company']).ne(df['company']).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output:
    id company  flag
0    1       A     0
1    1       A     0
2    1       B     1
3    2       C     0
4    2       C     0
5    2       C     0
6    3       D     0
7    3       E     1
8    3       F     1
9    4       G     0
10   5       H     0
11   5       I     1
12   5       J     1
```